# Move cursor to the next parameter in PhpStorm

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I want to move the cursor from here:

[image: The state before]

To here:

[image]

in a single step. Is there any such keyboard shortcut?

Right now I first have to enter the right arrow, then comma and then space which is a task quite cumbersome on my keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't but you could create a live template to get something simpler. So you can create a live template live this:

```
$PARAMONE$, $PARAMTWO$, $PARAMTHREE$, $PARAMFOUR$ $END$
```

And you can call this `param4`, and once you type that in, and press tab, it will load up areas that you can type into and just press tab to get from one param to the other.

Other than that, there's no way I know of to do this.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about live templates and the example you posted works great.

Comment: @SimonBengtsson If this helped you, please consider giving it an upvote :)